# divs moving when zooming out and zooming in

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser

this is my html

```
<div class="span_sec_0mid">
 <div class="span_sec_banner">
  <div class="span_sec_banner_mid">
   <!--other divs--> 
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

and css is

```
.span_sec_0mid {    
height: 480px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}
.span_sec_banner {
display: block;
height: 479px;
margin: 70px auto 0;
overflow: hidden;
width: 1362px;
 }
.span_sec_banner_mid {
display: block;
height: 479px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1000px;
}
```

but when i zoom in or in big screens inner divs moving. how can i fix this. please help. thanks.

Comment: You code is inefficient. Can you share fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

use [transform-origin](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp) to 0px on dive which zoom. read more about  [transform-origin](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp)

The transform-origin property allows you to change the position of transformed elements.

```
 transform-origin: 0px 0px;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
-moz-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
-ms-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
```

i face same issue for zoom out/in feature for my website. i solve using above css code. see here screen shot

[image]